# How to find out the SQLs in MySQL which were not executed?

Tags: mysql

Some of our SQLs are halting MySQL and not processed. We want to find out which SQLs origins the problem. How can we get the last SQL which dropped the MySQL server and was not executed?

Comment: You could [start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+error+logging&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=mysql+error+logging&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2143j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) I guess. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I assume log collects only the processed sqls (successfull and non successful). The key problem is to catch the request which was not processed at all.

Comment: You're assuming things.... but did you actually read any of the links in those results? And what is the difference between "unsuccessful" and "not processed" exactly? I'm not clear what scenario you are describing. Do you mean queries which never even reach the server? Clearly MySQL cannot log something it does not receive.

Comment: Or do you mean something is crashing the server? If that's what you mean, then read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log.html where it says:

Comment: _"The error log contains a record of mysqld startup and shutdown times. It also contains diagnostic messages such as errors, warnings, and notes that occur during server startup and shutdown, and while the server is running. For example, if mysqld notices that a table needs to be automatically checked or repaired, it writes a message to the error log.

On some operating systems, the error log contains a stack trace if mysqld exits abnormally. The trace can be used to determine where mysqld exited. See Section 29.5, “Debugging and Porting MySQL”._

Comment: Based on that, I suggest you enable full error logging and then see if it logs anything when your issue occurs. And next time, please actually take some time to read the information people send you, instead of just making random assumptions...